# Trying to insert data in table view received from json not working,static data mean working fine objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

```
- (void)getDataForProjects{

     MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
     hud.mode = MBProgressHUDModeIndeterminate;
     hud.labelText = @"Processing...";

    [[HTTP_Helper sharedInstance] global_WebCall:NEWS_AND_EVENTS_URL completion:^(NSDictionary *json, NSError *requestError) {
    if (!requestError) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
        });

        Productarray = json ;

        NSLog(@"what is this %@",Productarray);

        for (int i=0;i<Productarray.count;i++){
            _dict = [Productarray objectAtIndex:i];

            _ProjectidData = [_dict objectForKey:@"ProjectID"];
            _ProjectImgUrlData = [_dict objectForKey:@"ProjectImgUrl"];
            _ProjectTitleData = [_dict objectForKey:@"ProjectTitle"];
            _ProjectDescData = [_dict objectForKey:@"ProjectDesc"];


            NSLog(@" This title %@",_ProjectTitleData );
            NSLog(@" This imag %@",_ProjectImgUrlData);
            NSLog(@" This id  %@",_ProjectidData);
            // NSLog(@"what is this  %@",_ProjectTitleData);

        }

       // [self parseNewsAndEventsData:json];
    }

   }];
  }
```

Comment: What's your issue? There is no `[yourTableView reloadData];` once the parsing is done, and you don't do really anything with the new data. It's unclear.

Comment: i am trying to insert data witch i got from json response,if it is static data means all inputs are successfully inserting in cell(description,title,image) but in dynamic from json means data is not inserting and showing empty cells

Comment: - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return _ProjectTitleData.count;
}     cell.ongoing_title.text = [[_ProjectTitleData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"ProjectTitle"];
    
    cell.ongoing_descrption.text = [[_ProjectDescData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"ProjectDesc"];                this how i am inserting is this is right way to insert or else have to use any if condition for get the data